# How is a Runabout secured against theft?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, spaceship, crime

It is pretty common in *DS9* that two officers go on a mission, typically to the Gamma Quadrant, and beam down to the surface (or another ship).

The Runabout's computer is portrayed to be slightly more deliberate than a shuttle or the Enterprise computer in that it will respond to commands like 'prepare do a warp tow' or 'beam us up'.   And also more likely to volunteer information.

But it's not rare for the crew to be out of contact with the Runabout while it happily floats around in orbit.   And Runabouts are not huge ships.   So it seems entirely feasible to either beam aboard the ship or put it in tow with the goal of capturing a valuable asset.

Clearly, Starfleet hasn't failed to consider this.   What do we see in canon?

## What security measures are in place to prevent theft of Runabouts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**What security measures are in place?**

You can lockout the bridge functions in a Runabout, as seen in ["The Jem'Hadar"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Jem%27Hadar_(episode)), however, those security measures aren't always in place, as seen in ["Paradise."](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Paradise_(episode)), which almost exactly describes the scenario you asked about.

Sisko and O'Brien beam down to a planet leaving the Runabout in orbit unmanned. The Runabout is essentially "hijacked" and sent off to be destroyed in the DS9 episode ) by an anti-technology hippie, who is on the planet.

> However, when Sisko attempts to contact their runabout, he finds it missing. Alixus emerges and admits that she destroyed the runabout and even helped invent the device that created the duonetic field in the first place. - Memory-Alpha

Sisko expected his runabout to patiently be waiting for him in orbit. However, Alixus had contacted the Runabout and either beamed aboard and/or programmed it to fly into a star. She wasn't Starfleet, so she shouldn't have had access, but she clearly did.

> Further investigation reveals that it has been exposed to intense gamma radiation resulting from a close proximity to Orellius Minor, a nearby star. Dax hypothesizes that someone tried to destroy the Rio Grande by flying it into the star, for if the trajectory were slightly off, the gravity of the star could have deflected the ship and sent it in a new direction.

Dax and Kira eventually backtrack the Runabout's route to the planet Sisko and O'Brien are "trapped" on.

**Additional**

Star Trek as a whole has a history of people being able to use vessels without authorization (most notably those Klingon Birds-of-Prey), although we do see some security actions being taken.

***Security Examples:***

The Defiant (in ["Defiant"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Defiant_(episode))) has a bridge lockout code, which must be entered before the ship's systems can be accessed.

In [First Contact](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_First_Contact) when Picard realizes the Borq are on his ship he has Data lockout the main computer so that none of the primary functions can be used.

Riker *manages* to lockout the computer in TNG ["Rascals"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rascals_(episode)) while Ferengi are attempting to steal the ship. - thanks [Politank-Z](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/44480/politank-z)

Jake and Nog locked out of the Runabout in ["The Jem'Hadar"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Jem%27Hadar_(episode)) - thanks [Politank-Z](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/44480/politank-z)

***Lack of Security Examples:***

The aforementioned episode "Paradise."

Daimon Bok is able to pilot the abandoned starship Stargazer (TNG ["The Battle"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Battle_(episode)))

Khan is his people are able to commandeer the [Reliant](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Khan_Noonien_Singh#The_beginning_of_vengeance) in Wraith of Khan.

Kirk ([ST3: Search For Spock](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_III%3A_The_Search_for_Spock)), Dukat (DS9 ["Return to Grace"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Return_to_Grace_(episode))), Augments (ENT ["Borderland"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Borderland_(episode))), and Ferengi (TNG ["Rascals"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rascals_(episode))) easily commandeer Birds-of-Prey. All they had to do was get on the ship.

Archer and his crew are able to capture and eventually fly a Suliban Cell Ship (ENT ["Broken Bow"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Broken_Bow_(episode)))

Comment: I don't think you can argue "nothing" from this example. It's more reasonable to assume that she *defeated* the security measures rather than that there are none

Comment: @Richard with all of her knowledge as a hippie? Sure she worked with people to help invent the anti-technology field, but is she also an expert cracker?

Comment: Except she didn't destroy the runabout.   That was a lie, I suppose.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Not for lack of trying. See my added quote.

Comment: Well, that all just seems like a plot hole you can fly a runabout through.  Especially with the Maquis around, who would be thrilled to acquire one of those.

Comment: @JackBNimble - We don't really know what her skills are, other than that she's an expert in duotronic field design and evidently a highly competent engineer.

Comment: @Richard Memory-Alpha claims "With the help of like-minded, influential scientists on Earth, she had designed a duonetic field-device, capable of rendering any other, nearby technology inoperable. " That suggests she worked with scientists, not necessarily that she is one herself, or an expert.

Comment: @JackBNimble - Duotronic, duonetic, potato, potato.

Comment: @Richard She is this expert engineer and everything, but not smart enough to hit a STAR with a spaceship?

Comment: @JackBNimble:   Well, aiming anything from 1 AU away is going to be damn near impossible if there's no feedback or mid-course corrections.

Comment: @JackBNimble Don't forget Jake & Nog being locked out of the runabout controls in DS9: The Jem'Hadar.

Comment: Also, Riker locking down command functions in TNG: Rascals. I don't think Khan is a good example of lack of security - he had Reliant's Captain and First Officer under his mental control.

Comment: "when Picard realizes the **Borq** are on his ship"  http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_me12m2uj5U1r2dhipo1_r1_500.jpg

Comment: I feel like the Stargazer is a special exception to this. You point out it was abandoned. Depending on when Daimon Bok acquired it, he could have had *several years* to break the security on the ship. Also consider that the age of the ship meant it could probably have used a few software patches. Just like computer systems today, I would consider aged ships without regular updates to be highly vulnerable regardless of what security measures it may or may not have had when it was in service.

Comment: @Politank-Z:  [They got there first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRY5F2IsKRs)